# Is a custom rom which is designed for rk2918 tablet will run on any tablet with rk2918 cpu

Tags: custom-roms

I have 3q rc0710b tablet .. the cpu is Rockchip RK2918.
I am looking for a custom rom for this slow tablet ,to get better performance..
can I try any rk2918 custom rom ?
Where can I get best rom ?

Answer (score 1):

A ROM that is designed to run on an RK2918 *will not* run on any RK2918 chipset.  The ROM still needs to be built for your device specifically.

Check XDA-Developers for a ROM for your tablet.